# Want to click on a button using cucumber/selenium

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, cucumber-jvm

I'm new to cucumber tests. I want a help in which Webpage contains a button where I want to click. I tried my possible ways which are: 
(1) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Add New')]")).click();  
(2) driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add New")).click(); 
(3) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@ng-click='addNewSelection*']")).click(); 
(4) String str = driver.findElement(By.tagName("button")).getAttribute("ng-click"); 
(5) String productHref = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Properties")).getAttribute("href"); 
(6) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/header/nav/ol/li[2]/a")).click();


None of the above worked. Here is my html:

```
    <button class="btn btn-default om-add-new-btn ng-binding" ng-click="addNewSelection()">Add New</button>
```

Comment: I move further in this and found out that it works using angularjs protractor. I tried through that. But still got this error when I try to access an element using element(by.model('model')).sendKeys('AD');:
Failures:

  1) Description of block
   Message:
     UnknownError: unknown error: angular is not defined
  (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.134)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7
d3),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)
   Stacktrace:
     UnknownError: unknown error: angular is not defined
  (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.134)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium makes an awesome web driver for cucumber tests, however it can be a rather wordy and complicated tool for test steps.

I would thoroughly recommend using the capybara gem for any web related steps.

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

Then, once configured, you can simply use the following code to click the button:

```
click_button('Add New')
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Pheonexx for your help but in my company I need to use only angularjs. I spent 2 days for this but still unable to find the solution.